# Can I update the In App Purchase content for spacific App version?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am working on one application where I need to update the In-App purchase content for dual language support, now the App is rewritten from objective c to swift and it can download and play the new content but the problem is if I upload the new content old users will not be able to download them and use them, so is it possible that I could limit the new app content version to specific App version (suppose if newly uploaded content version is now 2 and new app version is 4). I am not able to figure it out is it possible or not or what else can be done. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your better option is to change your download code in your *new* version to only download the new-format content. That way, your existing app users (who don't want to update to your new version, for whatever reason), will continue to see the old-format IAP content, and new users + all users who upgrade will see the new-format IAP content.

Comment: This is changed but I have doubt like when the new content version is up and user try to buy it and after purchase, they aren't able to use it, How can I prevent that situation?